# PDO PHP how to customize header function

Tags: php

is there any way i can get the id inside this code:

```
header('Location: assigned.php?success?$ticket_id');
```

I am new to PDO. sorry for the simple question

Comment: Why do you think it's related to PDO?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes, there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `?` twice. it should be like..

```
header('Location: assigned.php?success='.$ticket_id);
```

Comment: you got it right Sumit,thanks a lot!